# How to attain predictive response values used for vis.gam plots?

Tags: gam

Is it possible to get the predicted response values that are used to plot 3D contour plots in vis.gam. I want to know what the predicted response for each grid cell is in the plot. I am using the MGCV package and GAM function. My model is:

```r
pose_mod <- gam(POSEtrans ~ s(Elevation) + s(Heatload) + 
                  s(Precip_Spring_Fall_Total) + s(PSSP6) + s(BRTE) +
                  TSF + s(PointID, bs = 're'), 
                family=betar(link='logit'), method = "REML",
                data = iData) 

vis.gam(pose_mod, view=c("BRTE", "Elevation"),
        type = 'response',theta=45,ticktype="detailed", n.grid = 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know is to use my {gratia} package (you'll need the development version on GitHub, which you can install using the intructions on the GitHub site: https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/ or if you can't build from sources, use the binary builds from R-universe: https://gavinsimpson.r-universe.dev/ui#package:gratia).

```r
library("gratia")

ds <- data_slice(pose_mod, BRTE = evenly(BRTE, n = 20),
                 Elevation = evenly(Elevation, n = 20))
```

This follows the conventions in {mgcv} and `vis.gam()`, such that you get the same grid of points. The you could `predict()` (from {mgcv} or use `fitted_values()` from {gratia} with `ds` to get the predicted expectation of the response for each grid cell:

```r
fitted_values(pose_mod, data = ds, scale = "response")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Gavin. I ran the code you provided, but the results return the fitted values even though the scale is "response" which is what I am needing. Any ideas why I'm not getting the vales on the response scale or a way to convert the fitted values to the response scale?

Comment: No idea; assuming you have the code correctly entered (not that if doing `predict()` the default is to predict on the link scale, but if you choose `type = "response"` there, you won't be able to create a credible interval on the fitted values. This is the main reason for `gratia::fitted-values()` - I was tired of typing the code needed to predict on the link scale, create the interval and then back transform everything to the response scale.